# Can't get Android to run in Ionic because of a PATH error I don't understand.

Tags: android, macos, path, terminal, ionic-framework

I get this error message now.

```
Error: ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existant path: 
at /Users/SubjectiveEffect/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:162:19
```

My .bash_profile looks like this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/SubjectiveEffect/Development/android-sdk-macosx

export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

and the path to the android SDK (that I got from here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

is indeed "Users/SubjectiveEffect/Development/android-sdk-macosx".

I just cannot understand why I'm getting this error. I've changed the .bash_profile according to the other advice on this site (and others). How can it be wrong?

When I use "echo $PATH" I get this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Development/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

When you `echo $PATH` the output is showing multiple locations for the required `platform-tools` and `tools` folders (that contain Android SDK etc that are needed to build your project)

I've removed the semicolons for clarity - the following locations are all in your PATH

```
/Development/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/platform-tools
/Development/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools
/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools
/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

none of which match up with what you have in your `.bash_profile` It might be as simple as a stale environment, quite possible if you've only just edited your `.bash_profile` - the file is only run when you start a new Terminal session so open a new Terminal window (or if you're getting this error in your IDE then try a close / restart) and try building again.

If you're still having problems can you run `echo $PATH` from a new Terminal window and post your entire `.bash_profile`?